# accessing table cells from puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I need to be able to validate the values in specific table cells, and later, to click on a particular cell that holds a link. I get that Node and the browser (or emulator) are two different process spaces, so I can't pass references. I was hoping that puppeteer would hide this fact in a read-only manner such as `return someArray;` in a function run in the browser context being "magically" replicated by puppeteer on the Node side, but alas.

```
test("get a certain row from a certain table", async function getRow() {
    await page.waitForSelector("#actionItemsView-table");
    const
        cellText = await page.evaluate(function getCells() {
            const
                row = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#actionItemsView-table tbody tr"));
            for (let i = row.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                // the row we want is the one that has text of interest in cells[2]
                if (row[i].cells[2] === "some text that identifies the row of interest") {
                    return row[i];  // we can't pass this back to Node, so this is wrong
                                    // but some version of this what we need to do
                }
            }
            return null; // no such row
        });
        console.log(cellText); // cellText is an empty array
}, testTimeout);
```

Lacking that, I have run through various intermediate experiments, all the way to this, seemingly simplest case, just to get *something* that works and then work my way back up to what I need, but this doesn't work either:

```
test("get the text from a single cell", async function getInnerText() {
    await page.waitForSelector("#actionItemsView-table");
    const
        cellText = await page.evaluate(function getText() {
            let
                ct,
                row = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#actionItemsView-table tbody tr"));
            for (let i = row.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (row[i].cells[2] === "some text that identifies the row of interest") {
                    ct = row[i].cells[3].innerText; // the text of the next cell to the right
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ct; // ct is not a string!
        });
        console.log(cellText); // cellText is undefined!
}, testTimeout);
```

If I do things like

```
document.querySelect("#actionItemsView-table").rows[2].cells[3].innerText
```

they work, so my selectors and javascript syntax seems to be correct.

There has to be a way to do this and it has to be way easier than I have made it -- what am I missing? Why is the above not working but something like this does work:

```
await page.$eval("input[name=emailAddr]", function setId(el,  id)  { el.value = id; return id; }, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to find that cell:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  let td = [...document.querySelectorAll("td")].find(td => td.innerText === "something")
  return td?.nextElementSibling?.innerText
})
```

This will return the text or undefined

Comment: Thanks, but `console.log(cellText);` in the above still yields 'undefined'. Also, in the real application I need the whole row, not just the innerText from one cell. It doesn't seem possible to get even the text, let alone an array of objects. I know this has to be possible, but I don't see what I've done to make it not work.

Comment: If it's not there you probably have to wait for it.

Comment: I tried using a setTimeout to wait, nope. I tried inserting some intervening actions to take up a bit of time (with await prepended), nope. Hmm.

Comment: Maybe try `match` instead: `td.innerText.match(/something/i)`

Comment: Also make sure it's not in an iframe. If so you need to evaluate there.

Comment: pguardiario -- thank you for staying with this. It's not in an iframe. It's not that the data is not found. I can tell from the code in the browser context that it is functioning as expected (and finding a match). The problem is in crossing the border from browser context to Node. For lack of progress, I am going to switch to Cypress.io, which runs entirely in the browser.